# NetworkX spring_layout() not so springy anymore?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx, network-analysis

This question is a bit abstract, and I know these are generally frowned upon, but bear with me please.

I have notebooks from a year or two ago, where I used `networkx` to draw networks. They were springy and most nodes aligned nicely along an oval outline.

Upgraded to version 2+, now visualizations are a lot less 'springy' and imho less user friendly / harder to understand.

`nx.draw()` default layout is a spring layout, and you can also pass 
`pos=nx.spring_layout(graph, k=X, iterations=Y)` to the `draw()` method. 
I tried playing around with the parameters `k` and `iterationand couldn't get very far.

Since my visualizations are gone, I'll give an example using someone else's code. Here is the [source](https://blog.hipolabs.com/network-analysis-fundamentals-5981cbd65ffd).

Visualization in the source:

[image]

(credit: [hipolabs](https://blog.hipolabs.com/))

Visualization re-created by me, NetworkX version 2.1:

[image]

Any thoughts? Was there really a change in how spring layout behaves in version 2+ versus older ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The defaults for iterations and k have not changed, but they did add a threshold parameter for stopping the algorithm. I would have a look at the source code:
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/drawing/layout.py
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/_modules/networkx/drawing/layout.html#fruchterman_reingold_layout